# Javascript For loop - undefined error with index variable, but not with an integer

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have an array of values "purchasedDiscount" that I parse from HTML.  Outside of the loop it holds a value.  Inside the loop I get output when using a 0 in the index.  When I try to get the values using the counter "i" from the for loop I get "undefined".  I have no idea why this is happening.  I am using Prototype JS, but I feel this is a JS issue directly with my syntax (could be wrong).

```
    var purchasedDiscount = $$('.cm-purchased-discount > span.price');
    console.log("Purchased Discount: " + purchasedDiscount[0].innerHTML);

    for (i = 0; i < cmItems.length; i++) {
        console.log("i: " + i);
        console.log("length of loop: " + cmItems.length);
        console.log(parseFloat(stripPriceFormatting(purchasedPrice[i].innerHTML)));
        console.log("Purchased Discount 0: " + purchasedDiscount[0].innerHTML);
        console.log("Purchased Discount i where i is 0: " + purchasedDiscount[i].innerHTML);
    }
```

Here is my Console output

```
(index):1280 Purchased Discount: £0.00
(index):1287 i: 0
(index):1288 length of loop: 2
(index):1289 679
(index):1290 Purchased Discount 0: £0.00
(index):1291 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined
```

stripPriceFormatting Delcation

```
function stripPriceFormatting(price) {
    var priceFormats = ["$", "£"];
    var strippedFormatting = price;
    for (i=0; i < priceFormats.length; i++) {
        strippedFormatting = strippedFormatting.replace(priceFormats[i], "");
    }
    console.log("Stripped Formatting: " + strippedFormatting);
    return strippedFormatting.replace(",", "");
}
```

Comment: could you show the declaration for `stripPriceFormatting` , maybe that's changing `i`

Comment: ahh, quite possible, but I assumed it would localize to that for loop.  Will change the stripPriceFormatting loop to 'j'

Comment: yeah that's it !

Comment: Fixed, thanks!  Can you post an answer ?

Comment: You're making a single global variable called `i`. You need `for (var i = 0` in both cases. Don't use `j` instead, **fix your variable declarations**.

Comment: I'd suggest using let instead of var though.

Comment: @Angels **in this case having block scoping isn't really necessary**, declaring the variable with `var` will scope it internally to the function, and that's enough.

Comment: meagar, can you describe how you would do this?  Angels, what does "let" do?  I'm looking it up now.  How would it help me here?

Comment: @maioman and what if he someday will make two for loops in the same function with 'i'?

Comment: I have scoped them locally maioman with var in each loop.  Thanks to you and Maioman.  If there are better ways to define these I am open to this.

Comment: @camdixon var scopes variable to the nearest function, let scopes it to the nearest block, in your situation 'for' block. Also syntax checkers prefer let and show warnings when var is used in such situations.